# How can I create an SQL Date using a Json Map in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, json, date

I would like to save a date to a MySql database in the `java.sql.Date format:`

```
new Date();
```

Output: **Fri Sep 04 16:47:40 BST 2015**

I need to get the date from a Json Map:

```
created": {

    "date": 3,
    "day": 4,
    "hours": 14,
    "minutes": 49,
    "month": 8,
    "nanos": 0,
    "seconds": 59,
    "time": 1441288199000,
    "timezoneOffset": -60,
    "year": 115

}

Map<String, Object> dateMap = (Map<String, Object>) dateJsonObject;
```

How can I correctly format a new sql Date object using the values in the above date Map?

Comment: If you're using Date() in Java, consider using jodatimes DateTime(), makes working with dates far easier. http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your Json data includes time fields, I assume you are referring to a MySQL `DATETIME` datatype, not the `DATE` datatype.

For sending a `DATETIME` value to MySQL from Java, you need a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

If you don't have timezone issues, the simplest way is to use the `time` value:

```
new Timestamp(1441288199000L)
```

With timezone issues, you should either adjust for timezone by using the `timezoneOffset`, or apply all the other fields to a `Calendar`.

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

I recommend doing most of your work in the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework, built into Java 8 and later. ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html))

[`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is the class at the heart of java.time, representing a point along the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone. The Instant class tracks time in [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond)-since-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) but has a factory [method taking a count in milliseconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-).

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = 1441288199000L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisecondsSinceEpoch );
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2015-09-03T13:49:59Z

### JDBC

Eventually JDBC drivers will be updated to use the new java.time types directly. But in the meantime we need to convert to [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

The `java.sql.Timestamp` has new additional methods for conversion to/from java.time.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
String tsAsString = ts.toString( );
```

> 2015-09-03 06:49:59.0

Note the well-intentioned but unhelpful feature in java.sql.Timestamp where its [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--) implementation silently applies your [JVM’s current default time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-). Even worse, it fails to append any indicator of the adjusted time zone thereby making this string worse than worthless.

Here java.sql.Timestamp’s [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--) applied my time zone [`America/Los_Angeles`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Los_Angeles), shifting the date-time back seven hours. Same moment on the timeline as the [`Instant::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) output seen above, just represented by the [wall-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) of US west coast. One of many reasons to avoid these old classes as much as possible and instead use java.time as much as possible.

## java.sql.Date

The Question asked for java.sql.Date which is a date-only (in UTC) without any time-of-day.

Actually a java.sql.Date has both (time of 00:00:00.0 in UTC) but pretends not to have them. (This class is a bad hack from the early days of Java.)

To get a `java.sql.Date` we need a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) which we can get from a `LocalDateTime` which we can get from our `Instant`.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant( instant , ZoneOffset.UTC ).toLocalDate();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

> localDate : 2015-09-03
>   sqlDate : 2015-09-03

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try..

From JSON the time value + hour+ minute+ sec, you will have is Sep 3 14:49:59 , so GMT will be Sep 03 13:49:59... Time offset is 60 minutes between BST and GMT.. BST is 1hr ahead of GMT..

```
    //assuming you need time adjusted to GMT...
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(1441288199000L);//"time": 1441288199000 >>> 2015-09-03
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 14);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -60*60*1000); //timezone adjust, since you have the offset..
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()) ;
```